# How to train the original U-Net model with PyTorch?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, pytorch, image-segmentation

I’m trying to implement and train the [original U-Net model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04597.pdf), but I’m stuck in when I’m trying to train the model using the [ISBI Challenge Dataset](http://brainiac2.mit.edu/isbi_challenge/).

According with the original U-Net model, the network outputs an image with 2 channels and size of 388 x 388. So, my data loader for training generates a tensor with size of *[batch, channels=1, width=572, height=572]* for the input images and *[batch, channels=2, width=388, width=388]* for target/output images.

My problem actually is that when I’m trying to use the nn.CrossEntropyLoss() the following error is raised:

> RuntimeError: invalid argument 3: only batches of spatial targets supported (3D tensors) but got targets of dimension: 4 at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1556653099582/work/aten/src/THNN/generic/SpatialClassNLLCriterion.c:59

I’m just starting with PyTorch (newbie here)… so, I’ll really appreciate if someone could help me to overcome this problem.

The sourcecode is available on GitHub:

https://github.com/dalifreire/cnn_unet_pytorch
https://github.com/dalifreire/cnn_unet_pytorch/blob/master/unet_pytorch.ipynb

Best regards!

**UPDATE**

I just remove the channel dimension from my masks and everything works well… now I’m generating masks with the shape 1 [width=388, height=388].

After that, I’m working with input images (X), target masks (y) and predicted output masks (y_hat) as follow:

```
X     --> torch.Size([10, 1, 572, 572])
y     --> torch.Size([10, 388, 388])
y_hat --> torch.Size([10, 2, 388, 388])
```

But, I don’t understand why target masks (y) and predicted masks (y_hat) must have different shapes? It’s so weird for me…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the CrossEntropyLoss docstring of PyTorch:

```
Shape:

    - Input: :math:`(N, C)` where `C = number of classes`, or
      :math:`(N, C, d_1, d_2, ..., d_K)` with :math:`K \geq 1`
      in the case of `K`-dimensional loss.

    - Target: :math:`(N)` where each value is :math:`0 \leq \text{targets}[i] \leq C-1`, or
      :math:`(N, d_1, d_2, ..., d_K)` with :math:`K \geq 1` in the case of
      K-dimensional loss.

    - Output: scalar.
      If :attr:`reduction` is ``'none'``, then the same size as the target:
      :math:`(N)`, or
      :math:`(N, d_1, d_2, ..., d_K)` with :math:`K \geq 1` in the case
      of K-dimensional loss.
```

If your targets contain the class indices already, you should remove the channel dimension.

[Source](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/only-batches-of-spatial-targets-supported-non-empty-3d-tensors-but-got-targets-of-size-1-1-256-256/49134)